# ¿Por qué se llama "noche toledana" a una noche que se pasa sin poder conciliar el sueño?

Tags: etimología, modismos

En el Diccionario de la Lengua se indica que [**noche toledana**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QYCkgqb) es

> 1. f. coloq. noche que se pasa sin poder conciliar el sueño.

¿Por qué se llama *noche toledana*? ¿Hay alguna diferencia / matiz / preferencia de uso entre una **noche toledana** y [**pasar la noche en blanco**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5eNsBBo), que también es "sin dormir"?

Comment: Me recuerda lo descrito por Luis Buñuel en su autobiografía: noches en blanco correteando disfrazados y ebrios por las calles toledanas. Pero eso lo hacía en los años 30 del siglo XX y la expresión es mucho más antigua.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia ofrece en su artículo [Jornada del foso de Toledo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jornada_del_foso_de_Toledo):

> La frase "pasar una noche toledana", para indicar que no se ha
>   dormido, puede hacer referencia a estos sucesos narrados [una masacre que se recuerda con el nombre *Jornada del Foso*],​ si bien
>   otras fuentes hacen referencia al calor «agobiante».​ Por otra parte,
>   Sebastián de Covarrubias, en su Tesoro de la lengua castellana o
>   española (1611), afirmaba que la noche toledana era aquella que «se
>   pasa de claro en claro, sin poder dormir, porque los mosquitos
>   persiguen a los forasteros que no están prevenidos de remedios como
>   los demás».